# nested select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been working with sql for just under a year and have run across something that first appeared to be simple, but I can't get the syntax correct.

I am trying to join an additional table (table name = "device") and use another field in that table (hierlevel) to limit the results of the following query:

```
select deviceid, inventorydate, case when DeltaVersion ='' then '000'

              else DeltaVersion end as DeltaVersion,

--            CurrentATMVersion
              cast(CurrentATMVersion as varchar(50)) as 'CurrentATMVersion',

--            InstallATMVersion
              cast(InstallATMVersion as varchar(50)) as 'InstallATMVersion',

--            InstallDyDVersion
              cast(InstallDyDVersion as varchar(50)) as 'InstallDyDVersion',

              ATMInstallDate,

--            Java Version
              cast(JavaVersion as varchar(50)) as 'JavaVersion',

--            Chrome Version
              cast(ChromeVersion as varchar(50)) as 'ChromeVersion'
            
            from (SELECT a.[deviceid] ,

              a.[inventorydate],

              cast(a.[inventorydata].query('   for $b in /proviewinventoryfile/Section[@type="pvinvent"]/Component[@type="Software"]/Component[@name="ATM40"]//*

                                                            where $b/Name = "DeltaVersion"

                                                            return (data($b/Value))') as varchar(50)) as "DeltaVersion",

              cast(a.[inventorydata].query('  for $b in /proviewinventoryfile/Section[@type="pvinvent"]/Component[@type="Software"]/Component[@name="ATM40"]//*

                                                                     where $b/Name = "CurrentATMVersion"

                                                                     return (data($b/Value))') as varchar(50)) as "CurrentATMVersion",

              cast(a.[inventorydata].query('  for $b in /proviewinventoryfile/Section[@type="pvinvent"]/Component[@type="Software"]/Component[@name="ATM40"]//*

                                                                     where $b/Name = "InstallATMVersion"

                                                                     return (data($b/Value))') as varchar(50)) as "InstallATMVersion",

              cast(a.[inventorydata].query('  for $b in /proviewinventoryfile/Section[@type="pvinvent"]/Component[@type="Software"]/Component[@name="ATM40"]//*

                                                                     where $b/Name = "InstallDyDVersion"

                                                                     return (data($b/Value))') as varchar(50)) as "InstallDyDVersion",

              cast(a.[inventorydata].value('(/proviewinventoryfile/Section[@type="pvinvent"]/Component[@type="Software"]/Component[@name="ATM40"]/ValueItem[3]/Value )[1]','nvarchar(max)' ) as varchar(100))  as "ATMInstallDate",

             
              cast(a.[inventorydata].query('  for $b in /proviewinventoryfile/Section[@type="pvinvent"]/Component[@type="Software"]/Component[@name="JavaSoft"]//*

                                                                     where $b/Name = "Java Version"

                                                                     return (data($b/Value))') as varchar(50)) as "JavaVersion",

              cast(a.[inventorydata].query('  for $b in /proviewinventoryfile/Section[@type="pvinvent"]/Component[@type="Software"]/Component[@name="Google Settings"]//*

                                                                     where $b/Name = "Chrome Version"

                                                                     return (data($b/Value))') as varchar(50)) as "ChromeVersion"

  FROM [proview].[dbo].[inventory] as a 

  INNER JOIN

  (    SELECT [deviceid], max ([inventorydate] ) as id

         FROM [proview].[dbo].[inventory]

         group by deviceid
                 
  ) as b

on b.id = a.inventorydate

and b.deviceid = a.deviceid)  c;
```

I do not know where to put the inner join statement -
the common fields in both tables are deviceid
looking to limit the results to those in the above query where device.hierlevel like '0.12%'

thx in advance for any assistance

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! ([mcve])

Comment: i am using MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio

Comment: @jarlh - when i run the script I posted I get the deviceid field with 769 records.  there are several records I would like to omit from the query.  the field I need to use to select only the records I want is in a table named "device".  the field i need to use to filter out the unwanted records is called "hierlevel".  i am asking for a join between the existing script I posted and this - "select deviceid
from device
where hierlevel like '0.12%'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery you call b is the place where you decide which inventory rows to pick, so I'd place the device lookup there:

```
FROM proview.dbo.inventory as a 
INNER JOIN
(   
  SELECT i.deviceid, max(i.inventorydate) AS max_inventorydate
  FROM proview.dbo.inventory i
  WHERE i.deviceid IN (SELECT d.deviceid FROM device d WHERE d.hierlevel LIKE '0.12%')
  GROUP BY i.deviceid
) AS b ON b.deviceid = a.deviceid AND b.max_inventorydate = a.inventorydate
```